# JPA/Hibernate: Missing table error

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to build a simple application using Hibernate JPA with MySQL but I keep getting a "Missing table" error whenever I try to deploy it to Wildfly.

My persistent class looks like this:

```
package com.example;

@Entity @Table
public class FooBar {
    //...
}
```

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="ExampleJPA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>com.example.FooBar</class>

        <properties>
            <!-- Configuring JDBC properties -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="(my user)" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="(my password)" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

            <!-- Hibernate properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />

            <!-- Configuring Connection Pool -->
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="2000" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And this is the message I get when deploying to a Wildfly 8 server:

**org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"ExampleJPA.war#ExampleJPA\": org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: FooBar
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: FooBar**

I do have a table called FooBar in the database. I can access it directly with JDBC using the same url, user and password defined in the persistence.xml. What is wrong with my JPA setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table doesn't exist in the schema, so the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` value of "validate" fails. Either create the table or change the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` value to "create" or "update".